# Django: composite fields or embedded classes (like JPA)?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose you have to model several classes that should have composite properties like *dimensions* (*width* and *height*) or *phone number* (*prefix*, *number* and *extension*).

In Java (using JPA 2) I'd create a *Dimensions* class and annotate it with `@Embeddable`. This causes *Dimension's* fields (e.g. *width* and *height*) to be embedded into every class that declares a property of type *Dimensions*.

How do you model these with Django while avoiding code duplication? It doesn't make sense to create a separate *Dimensions* model and reference it with a `ForeignKey` field. And the classes do not have enough in common to justify model inheritance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be over-thinking inheritance. Inheritance is and is actually the recommended method to composite models. The following is an example of how properly use model inheritance in Django:

```
class PhoneModelBase(model.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class PhoneModel(PhoneModelBase):
    # phone is here without typing it
    # the only restriction is that you cannot redefine phone here
    # its a Django restriction, not Python restriction
    # phone = models.CharField(max_length=12) # <= This will raise exception
    pass
```

So what this does is it creates a model `PhoneModelBase`, however the key here is that it uses `class Meta` with `abstract=True`.

Here is more of behind the scenes of what is going on and some explanation of some of the Python concepts. I assume that you are not aware of them since you mentioned Java in the question. These Python concepts are actually rather confusing concepts so my explanation is probably not full, or even confusing, so if you will not follow, don't mind. All you have to know is to use `abstact = True`. Here is the official doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes.

`Meta` attribute within `PhoneModelBase` is just that, an attribute. It is the same as any other attribute within the class, except its a class instance (remember that in Python classes and functions are first order members). In addition, Python has this thing called `__metaclass__` which you can add to you classes. `__metaclass__` defines a way of how an instance of a class is build. More about that [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation). Django uses these in how it creates model class instances.

So to create the `PhoneModelBase` class, the following is a rough outline:

- When an instance of the `PhoneModelBase` class (the class itself, not instance of class - `PhoneModelBase()`) is being created, the `__metaclass__` which comes from `model.Model` due to inheritance takes over the creation process
- Within the `__metaclass__`, Python calls the function which creates the actual class instance and passes to it all of the fields from the class you are trying to create - PhoneModelBase. That will include `phone`, `Meta` and any other fields you define
- It sees the `Meta` attribute and then it starts analyzing its attributes. According to the values of these attributes, Django will change the behavior of the model
- It sees the `abstract` attribute and then changes the logic of the class its trying to create - `PhoneModelBase` by not storing it in db

So then the `PhoneModelBase`, even though its definition looks very similar to a regular model, its not a regular model. It is just an abstract class which is meant to be used as composite in other models.

When other models inherit from `PhoneModelBase`, their `__metaclass__` will copy the attributes from the base model as if you manually typed those attributes. It will not be a foreign key on anything like that. All of the inherited attributes are going to be a part of the model and will be in the same table.

Hopefully all of this makes some sense. If not, all you have to remember is just to use `Meta` class with `abstract = True`.

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comment, you can also inherit from multiple base classes. So you can have `PhoneModelBase`, `DimensionsModelBase`, and then you can inherit from both of these (or more), and all of the attributes from all base classes will be present in your model.

Comment: Worth adding that Python supports multiple inheritance, so if you have many of these abstract classes defining fields for your model, you can inherit from all of them.

Comment: Thank you for your long description. I'm aware of the concept of abstract base models in Django. I was not aware that multiple inheritance is the recommended (?) way to do these things in Python / Django. Several other languages (for example C++) also support multiple inheritance, but afaik it is not recommended as the general case for everyday programmers because it has several fundamental problems.

Comment: To clarify, I usually try to avoid multiple inheritance in Python in general because there could be method conflicts (both classes implement same method). Not sure what is the official Python recommendation. However in Django it is different because Django uses `__metaclass__` and Django manually implements what attributes should be taken from what base classes, hence making it perfect for composition.

Comment: Inheritance will still flatten all attributes at top level, while JPA's `@Embeddable` lets you collect the related dimension attributes to a nested object in the model, i.e. `model.dimensions.width` and that is way more powerful than mixins.